# Impugned and pugn'd

Tags: contractions, literature

In Jingo, by Terry Pratchet, Lord Vetinari says:

> "... Sergeant Colon and Corporal Nobbs have never *been* pugn'd in their entire lives."

What about "pugn'd"? Is it just a contraction for "impugned" or there is pun that a non-native like me can't spot?

Comment: Clearly the origin of *pwnd* ;-).

Comment: @Peyter pwned is from a typo of "owned". O/P are together on the extreme right of a querty keyboard.

Comment: @Martin Beckett: No shit, Sherlock. I'm pretty sure that was an attempt at humour by @Peter.

Comment: @Mr Disappointment - I didn't know what pwned meant until somebody pointed it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a joke. There are lots of words in English that are [back formations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-formation) like this.

The prefix 'im' often means to undo or the opposite of something. So 'impugned' sounds like it should be the negative of 'pugned', just as impolite is the opposite of polite.  In fact it's from the latin, impugnāre to fight against, attack.

A similar prefix is 'dis'. There is a joke in the same book (IIRC) describing Commander Vymes as disgruntled and Colon claiming that he was never gruntled to begin with.

Comment: Wikipedia's got a pretty good [explanation of back-formation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-formation) but the corresponding list of English back-formations is missing pugned/pugn'd. Guess Pratchett is one of the first to use it in print ;)

Comment: @aedia - more that it's a deliberately unused one, like gruntled, for the purpose of the joke.

Comment: @Martin - true, the list does seem to be intended for back-formations that are or were really used. Some seem just as amusing as "pugn" to me though. I'm now curious as to whether anyone really says that helicopters "helicopt" or that lasers "lase".

Comment: Lase is common - at least among people that need to discuss lasing.

Comment: @Martin - unfortunately, it's not only common but ambiguous.  Sometimes it's used to signify "what happens in the material/device/gap/whatever that generates a laser beam", and sometimes it means "what happens to the material on the receiving end"...

Comment: @MT_head - I only every used it for the material that is doing the emitting.

Comment: @Martin - and I agree that that is correct.  However, I've even heard the phrase "having your eyes lased", as in "getting LASIK surgery."  It makes my skin creep, it do.

Comment: One of my favorite fake back-formations is "have", pronounced "hayv".  She: "Behave!" I: "I _am_ have!  There are the haves and the have nots, and I am one of the haves!"  This joke really doesn't work in print, though...

Comment: @MT_Head: Oh, but it works even better in print!